# add text dynamically on img

Tags: javascript, html

I´ve still searched in some posts, but I haven´t an idea yet.

Objective:
I have an image (a yellow post-it 280px x 280px) and now, I want to be able to place text on the post-it after the user pushed a button e.g. "text".
I´m firm with html but not really with javascript.
thank you very much! martin

Comment: Do you want to create a new image with text in it, or do you just want to place text over an image? In the latter case, you could use a background image, or positioning.

Answer (score 3):

This is how I would do it.

Use a div with the post-it image as a background that has a child div for the note.

```
<div class='post-it'>
    <div class="note">
    </div>
</div>​
```

`div.note` can be easily positioned so that there's no overlap with the image.

```
.post-it {
    background-image: url('http://alternatewrites.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/06/post-it-note-with-a-pin.jpg');
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    width: 321px;
    height: 321px;
    position: relative;
}
.note {
    position: absolute;
    top: 90px;
    right: 30px;
    bottom: 30px;
    left: 60px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

And then the JavaScript is pretty straightforward:

```
// Execute after DOM has loaded
window.onload = function() {
    var postIt = document.getElementsByClassName('post-it'),
        addTextToNote = function () {
            //"this" is the textarea because the function is bound to the textarea;
            var note = this.parentNode,
                postIt = note.parentNode;
            note.removeChild(this);
            note.innerText = this.value;
            postIt.onclick = addTextArea;
        },
        addTextArea = function addTextArea() {
            //"this" is the div with class "post-it" because the function is bound to it;
            var note = this.getElementsByClassName('note'),
                t = null,
                i = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < note.length; i += 1) {
                t = document.createElement('textarea');
                t.rows = 10; // 10 rows and 25 columns is about
                t.cols = 25; // the correct size for the image
                t.value = note[i].innerText; // add any existing text
                t.onblur = addTextToNote;
                note[i].appendChild(t); // add textarea to note
                this.onclick = null; // remove click handler to prevent multiple click problems
                t.focus(); // give focus to the textarea
            }
        },
        i = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < postIt.length; i += 1) {
        postIt[i].onclick = addTextArea;
    }
};​
```

Mind you, in a production environment, I would also probably use jQuery for this as I find the syntax for DOM manipulation much simpler (and it's cross-browser, unlike the above example).

Here's a jsFiddle demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/gWf5Z/

Answer (score 1):

With your image I'd recommend putting it into a div element so it's easier to append.
With javascript I'd do the following:

```
addText(){
    var ele = document.createElement("p");
    ele.appendChild(document.createTextNode('your text'));
    document.getElementById('yourDiv').innerHTML(ele);

}
document.getElementById('yourButton').addEventListener('click', addText(), false);
```

As far as I know that should be correct. There are much easier methods. For instance Here's a CSS alternative.

HTML

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <p>text</p>
</div>
```

CSS

```css
#wrapper {background-image:url('post-it.png');}
#wrapper > p {display:none;}
#wrapper > img:hover p{display:block;}
```

Comment: for your CSS solution, wouldn't having the image in the background of div#wrapper be better?

Comment: @mtariq Yea I suppose :) was only an example